# What kind of UML diagrams should be in analysis model?

Tags: uml

As I know we have three base model in software modeling [Requirement, Analysis, Design], but I don't know what kind of diagrams should be in the analysis model. When someone asks me to give him Analysis model of the system, What should I give him?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An analysis model provides the information needed for the design. This includes:

- class roles (Text)
- use case description in terms of classes and operations
- completed analysis model classes (diagram)
- sub-system diagrams (package diagram)

You could basically see this as a refinement phase for the use cases aswell as containing the first initial class diagram.

---

As for how you would make such a model, you would start of by making a class diagram (draft). Once you have made this diagram you would have to re-examine your use cases and objects. Based on improvements you made you refine the class diagram.

This is followed by executing a check which results in more refinements of the class diagram. Finally you have to group the classes you found (decided) in packages (package diagram).

For further reading I would like to refer to [this article.](http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/A.Finkelstein/crsenotes/1B1499ANALYSIS.pdf)

Comment: I strongly doubt that it's a good idea to start with a class diagram. They should go last, after having finished on use cases, the dynamic view (e.g. activity diagrams) and components diagram.

Comment: I agree, though the article seems to refer to more abstract class diagrams for the initial approach. Also this isn't the first step in the design process.

Answer (score 0):

In the UML analysis model, you should create a class diagram which contains the view, controller and model classes, only the view classes contains methods but all of them contains attributes, here is an example http://www.cs.sjsu.edu/~pearce/modules/projects/ooa/sunUML/am.htm

Comment: And what would you create or which guidelines would you follow if the software is not going to use the [Model View Controller design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) at all?

Comment: In this case, i think you should create a first view of the class diagram with only the attributes, but i'm not sure about that

Comment: I don't know what are some other good and up-to-date sources, but Scott W. Ambler recommends to do some "_initial envisioning_" using `UML`: little bit of everything, don't get stuck on too many details but spend a few days on it. And refine/adjust the models/designs later repeatedly during the development. See chapter [Agile Modeling: Architecture Envisioning: An Agile Best Practice](http://agilemodeling.com/essays/initialArchitectureModeling.htm) for more. I think that Scott's `Domain Model` is close to what you mean by the `First View`. Book's chapter "Model Storming" looks useful too